# How to view html entity codes in page source of web browsers

Tags: html, entity

I grab/extract a remote webpage by php cURL. For this purpose I have to view the page source for the php script. Problem is that in remote page, some texts are within `<pre></pre>` tag. So, I can see the line breaks or other html entity code to which I want to grab that webpage part by part.

As for example, if you see the page source of http://dsebd.org/market-statistics.php, you can see that data under `TODAY'S SHARE MARKET`is showing under `<pre></pre>` tag. As `<pre>` preserves line break, so I can't assume what is there after each line of data.

How can I view the page source with that line break/newline/
 etc html entity codes?

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you need to find newlines, look for \n

Answer (score 1):

So you want to convert the text inside the`<pre></pre>` tag into HTML? Firstly the `nl2br` function will add `<br>` tags after each new line.

Everything else appears to be just spaces, so I would just do this:
 `$readable_text = str_replace(' ','&nbsp;',$html)`

But if you just wan't to grab the data piece by piece, its all in a standard format so all you need to do is grab it with simple regular expressions. So say you need to grab the data from each of these blocks of text:

```
All Category

ISSUES ADVANCED                 :                    133
ISSUES DECLINED                 :                    164
ISSUES UNCHANGED                :                     33
TOTAL ISSUES TRADED             :                    330


A Category (Equity)

ISSUES ADVANCED                 :                    101
ISSUES DECLINED                 :                    138
ISSUES UNCHANGED                :                     27
```

You can just use the new lines to search for and extract the specific data you need. Firstly, I'd load each block into an array.

NOTE: I see the `<pre></pre>` tag in your example has two main sections, the second one being:

```
                PRICES IN PUBLIC TRANSACTIONS : 2017-03-19
               ==========================================
```

You have to split these two sections up and process them individually. So for this job (I assume its extracting each individual bit of data from the text), the steps are:

1. split the two main sections up and process them separately
2. split each block in the first section up
3. split up each line in each block and extract the data you need from them

There are two ways to do this, either explode everything (since every section and subsection is separated by a different number of new lines, this will work effectively) like this:
    `$sections = explode('\n\n\n\n',$pre_text)`

or extract everything with regular expressions (or use a combination of both methods). I'll use regular expressions in this example, and won't explain step 1, just steps 2 and 3.

For splitting each block in section one into an array, you can use this regular expression:

```
$pattern = '/([A-Za-z \(\)]+)\n(.*?)\n\n/ms';
preg_match_all($pattern,$text,$blocks);
```

See it in action here:
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/jri
^^ Select **preg_match_all** or it won't work

Now **$blocks** is an array containing each block, since the pattern I used has two capture groups, the array contains the title of each block, and the text itself, heres what the array looks like:

[image]

So lets say you wanna grab every piece of data from each block, just loop through each block and run another regular expression that uses the spaces to catch the useful data, so it would be like this:

```
foreach($matches as $block) {
   preg_match_all('/([A-Za-z \(\).]+)[ ]+:[ ]+(.*?)\n/ms',$block,$lines)
}
```

and you get this:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your elaborative reply. It will be great help for me. But I want to show the line break code in page source. For example, if you see the page source for a red colored line -> `This is a sample text`, you may see it in page source as `<font color="red">This is a sample text</font>`. In the same way I can see a normal line break by `<font color="red">This is a sample text</font><br />`. But I can't see a line break in page source in texts in between `<pre></pre>` tag. i.e, I want to see line break here like this: `<font color="red">This is a sample text</font>nl2br`.